# Squashing a Large Branch with Several Merges with Itself

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a feature branch off of `master` as shown below.

```
              --S1--              (side branch)
             /      \
            /        \
     -F1---F2---F3---F4---F5-->   (feature branch - HEAD)
    /      /         /    /
   /      /         /    /
--M0-----M1---M2---M3---M4        (master)
```

I've bene working on this branch for a long time, so periodically I merge in any updates from `master`

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

I also collaborate with a few others so it's useful to branch off this `feature` branch to another `side-branch` where we safely do our work, and then merge that back into the `feature`

```
git checkout feature
git merge side branch
```

Let's say the `feature` branch has built up 100+ commits and I want to get the branch ready to merge into `master` by squashing everything.

I tried using a `git rebase`, but it only picks up those commits that are on my feature or side branch and ignores the merges (i.e. `F1`, `F3` and `S1`).

Usually this would be ok, but applying each of those one by one to `master` results in conflicts that I have to clear up. But I just did all that hard work to resolve conflicts when I created the merge commits `F2`, `F4`, and `F5`.

Is there a better way to do this?

One thought was that I could take the entire effective diff between `M0` and `F5` and somehow apply it as a patch to the end of `master` (`M4`). That seems messy though.

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question. Usually I use your last suggestion, which is to create a patch of the diff between M0 and F5, so as to minimize the conflict resolution later on.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just merge your feature back into `master`?  You'll end up with a single commit in `master` from a merge whether or not you do the squash.  I personally prefer to keep as much history as possible, unless of course you and you coworkers have sullied the feature with too many commits.